# sum two different table and the subtract its total

Tags: php, mysql

i have this problem with me on how to sum total value from two different table and then after getting its total i want to subtract it. for example i have table "rsales" and "sales" and i have these ff vlue below.

data from "rsales"

```
id | total | pcode |
1  | 100   | 2143  |
2  | 100   | 2143  |
3  | 50    | 2222  |
4  | 50    | 2222  |
```

data from "sales"

```
id | total | pcode |
7  | 100   | 2143  |
8  | 50    | 2222  |
```

my problem is this. i want to sum all "total" values from sales and sum "total"value from rsales group by pcode.and then after getting its sum i want to subtract it. my page  must be something like this.

```
   total    pcode
 | 100    | 2143  |
 | 50     | 2222  |
```

i have this ff code but it doesnt wor for me

```
sql "select sum(rsales.total)- sum(sales.total) as t1 where pcode = rsales.pcode"
```

Comment: What query are you using that is not working?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm guess the one missing the `FROM` clause...

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(r.total)-(
                   SELECT SUM(s.total) 
                   FROM sales AS s WHERE r.pcode=s.pcode
                  ) as total, 
    r.pcode 

    FROM rsales AS r 

    GROUP BY r.pcode;
```

Output:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+-
| total | pcode |
+--+--+--+--+--+-
| 100   | 2143  |
| 50    | 2222  |
+--+--+--+--+--+-
2 rows in set
```

Comment: I'm thinking a `JOIN` should also work, but sub-query seems much safer given the unknowns.

Comment: No idea, but it looks like it should work.  (I'm not the asker.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT
    SUM(L.total) as lTotal, SUM(R.total) as rTotal
FROM
    sales L
INNER JOIN rsales R 
    ON
        R.pcode = L.pcode
GROUP BY L.pcode
```

If you get expected values from both tables you can easily add Additions and Subtruction in FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

There's no joins needed to do this. This solution works if some pcodes are only in one table:

```
select SUM(total), pcode from (
        select sum(total) as total, pcode from rsales group by pcode
    union all
        select SUM(-total) as total, pcode from sales group by pcode) salesTables
 group by pcode
```